# Is the developer mode like the opened door for hackers to debug the mobile app?

Tags: mobile, appsec, debugging

The very good security recommendation is:  the mobile app should check if the developer mode is turned on and it should not start. Both in android and iOS. Do you agree with this sentence? What the development mode is threatened with?
Or what other requirements do you recommend in exchange for this?

Comment: This is highly subjective, but I would vehemently disagree with that statement.  I am a developer, almost ALL of my android devices have been rooted since the day I got them.  Its MY device, and if I payed for an app ... I should be the one to decide if it runs or not and with what permissions.  If you want to pop a warning to tell me im being dumb, and if anything happens its my fault ... sure, but it should be MY decision.

Comment: As a side note, if your think watching for debug mode is going to protect your code from being reverse engineered ... you need to do some more research.

Comment: If the security of your application depends on someone not being able to reverse-engineer it, you don't have any real security.  So no, I don't agree that making the app not run in developer mode offers any significantly increased security.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Your answers explained the subject to me.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's a terrible idea. A few reasons why:

- There are a lot of legitimate app developers, and they shouldn't need a separate phone to test their own app than they do to use yours.
- There are a lot of legitimate reasons for end-users to use development mode, such as using Helium Backup.
- It's really easy for any hacker even slightly more competent than a script kiddie to trick your program into thinking development mode is on when it's not.
- If your security model relies on trusting the client, it's as good as broken anyway, and you'd only be giving yourself a false sense of security.

Comment: _It's really easy for any hacker even slightly more competent than a script kiddie to trick your program into thinking development mode is on when it's not._ - I know nothing about Android or iOS, but I am curious to know how this would be possible. I'd imagine that developer mode cannot be spoofed by an unprivileged app.

Comment: @forest You're right that it can't be spoofed by an unprivileged app, but it's not hard to root an Android phone, and then you can do it with a privileged app.

Comment: @Joseph Sible Is it better to give a requirement that the application will not run when the system is rooted?

Comment: @globizer No, for almost exactly the same reasons.